# Не работает ajax подгрузка постов WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

Есть страничка постов с табами для каждой категории, выглядит это так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каждой вкладке соответственно выводятся посты из своей категории и подгрузка должна подгружать свои посты для каждой вкладки. Плюс здесь должен быть вывод из 4х конкретных категорий. На данный момент видно что в data-true-posts копки передаются какие-то данные, но кнопка вроде как показывает загрузку, пропадает и при этом посты новые не подгружает. Вывод постов из своей категории для каждой вкладки тоже работает.
Это страница блога, код в файле index.php:

```php
<?php $categories = get_categories([
                        'include'   => array(20,21,22,8)
                    ]);
                    foreach( $categories as $key => $category) : ?>
                    <?php $args = array(
                        'posts_per_page' => 1,
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                                    'field'     => 'term_id',
                                    'terms'     => $category -> term_id,
                                )
                            )
                    );

                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    // Цикл
                    if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                        <div class="tabs-content blog-preview">
                            <div class="row tabs-content_blog-content">
                            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="blog-card  blog-preview__item">
                                        <div class="blog-card__img irof">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="blog-card__body">
                                            <h3 class="text-h2 mb-20 blog-card__title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                            <div class="text-h4 mb-30 w-100"><?php the_date( 'd F Y' ); ?></div>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                                <p class="blog-card__text"><?php echo get_excerpt(400); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="blog-card__link">read more</a></p>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- col-->
                            </div>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <?php if (  $query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
                                <script>
                                    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
                                </script>

                                <div class="row page-location-content__btn justify-content-center">
                                    <button type="button" data-true_posts='<?php echo serialize($query->query_vars); ?>'
                                        data-current_page = '<?php echo (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>'
                                        data-max_pages='<?php echo $query->max_num_pages; ?>' class="loadmore_blog button">Show more</button>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Код в файле functions.php:

```php
function blog_load_posts(){
        $args = unserialize( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ) );
        $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
        $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $args['post_type'] = 'post';
        $args['posts_per_page'] = 1; // по сколько записей подгружать
        $args['tax_query'] = array( array( 'taxonomy'  => 'category', 'field'     => 'term_id', 'terms'     => $args['cat']));

        // обычно лучше использовать WP_Query, но не здесь
        query_posts( $args );
        // если посты есть
        if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ): the_post();

            echo '
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="blog-card  blog-preview__item">
                        <div class="blog-card__img irof">
                            '. get_the_post_thumbnail() .'
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog-card__body">
                            <h3 class="text-h2 mb-20 blog-card__title">'. get_the_title() .'</h3>
                            <div class="text-h4 mb-30 w-100">'. get_the_date( 'd F Y' ) .'</div>
                            <a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'">
                                <p class="blog-card__text">'. get_excerpt(400) .'<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'" class="blog-card__link">read more</a></p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ';

        endwhile; endif;
        die();
    }


    add_action('wp_ajax_loadmoreblog', 'blog_load_posts');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmoreblog', 'blog_load_posts');
```

Код в js файле:

```js
$('.loadmore_blog').click(function () {

        var el = $(this);
        var true_posts = el.attr('data-true_posts');
        var current_page = el.attr('data-current_page');
        var max_pages = el.attr('data-max_pages');

        $(this).text('Loading...'); // изменяем текст кнопки, вы также можете добавить прелоадер

        var $dataTarget = $(this).closest('.tabs-content').find('.tabs-content_blog-content');

        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmoreblog',
            'query': true_posts,
            'page': current_page
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, // обработчик
            data: data, // данные
            type: 'POST', // тип запроса
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    el.text('Show more'); // вставляем новые посты
                    current_page++; // увеличиваем номер страницы на единицу
                    el.attr('data-current_page', current_page);
                    if (current_page == max_pages) el.remove(); // если последняя страница, удаляем кнопку
                    $dataTarget.append(data);
                } else {
                    el.remove(); // если мы дошли до последней страницы постов, скроем кнопку
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: А куда вы запрос отправляете собственно? Что вам пишет во вкладке Network->XHR какой request и какой response, код ответа от сервера?

Comment: @Simon дело не в самом аяксе, он отрабатывает, это я уже проверила. да и у меня подобный код еще на 2х страницах нормально работает. здесь скорее в funcrions.php в $args что-то не то передается, мне кажется. Код скопировала полностью с другой страницы где он работал, а тут новое условие что выводить только из 4х категорий и вот в этом мне кажется что-то не получилось

Comment: @Simon в Network->XHR в файле admin-ajax.php во вкладке preview даже есть этот пост который должен подгрузиться, но который не отображается когда кнопка исчезает

Comment: Если пост есть в ответе, то проблема скорее всего в JS части

Comment: Где в вашем коде элемент $dataTarget ?

Comment: @Алексей в index.php в цикле первая обертка, далее в js вывожу эту обертку при обработке кода. Так как посты подгружаются по сути на месте кнопки, а мне необходимо что б верстка не ломалась. Там был неверно указан второй класс в js, поправила. но сути это не меняет, посты все равно не выводятся..этот элемент отвечает только за внешний вид верстки

Comment: @Alexa класс `tabs-content` вижу, а  `tabs-content__post-content` нет.

Comment: @Алексей поправила код, это опечатка была. все равно посты не выводит

Comment: @Alexa потому-что у вас tabs-content и blog-preview на одном уровне или это тоже опечатка? Откройте средства разраба в браузере в инспекторе нажмите на свою кнопку, а после впишите в консоль `jQuery($0).closest('.tabs-content').find('.blog-preview')` Там будет показано lenght 0 т.е. нет элемента.

Comment: @Алексей да, и правда lenght 0, но что именно поправить немного не поняла

Comment: @Alexa поменяйте просто на $(this).closest('.blog-preview') раз вам этот блок нужен

Comment: @Алексей кроме того, что кнопка чуть съехала в разметке, к сожалению, это не сработало

Comment: @Алексей вложенность классов напутала..поправила код выше, но сути это не меняет(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115917/discussion-between--and-alexa).